# how to hide specific content by winJS.UI on default html page

Tags: javascript, winjs

I want to show content 1 by default on my html page but when I click on h2 it will show content 2
and if I again click on h1 it will hide content 2 and show content 1. I tried this to hide

```
$(function () {
    $("#content2").hide(); 
});
```

but when I click on h2 it show nothing.I used this code

```
h1.onclick = function () {
            WinJS.UI.Animation.exitContent(content2 , { top: "0px", left: "350px" })
                .then(function () { return WinJS.Promise.timeout(200); })
                .done(function () { WinJS.UI.Animation.enterContent(content1, { top: "0px", left: "350px" }); 
h2.onclick = function () {
            WinJS.UI.Animation.exitContent(content1, { top: "0px", left: "350px" })
            .then(function () { return WinJS.Promise.timeout(1000); })
                .done(function () { WinJS.UI.Animation.enterContent(content1, { top: "0px", left: "350px" }); });
        };
```

Comment: I don't understand... you want to show `h1` and you want to click on `h2` but you're hiding it at the beginning (I guess), right? Could you please clarify what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this and see if it helps... h1 (`content1` in my code) appears visible, and when you tap on it, "it goes away" and `content2` appears

HTML

```
<div id="content1">
    <p>This is content 1</p>
</div>
<div id="content2">
    <p>This is content 2</p>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
content2.style.opacity = "0";

content1.onclick = function () {
    WinJS.UI.Animation.exitContent(content1, { top: "0px", left: "350px" }).then(
        function () {
            return WinJS.Promise.timeout(200);
        })
        .done(function () {
            WinJS.UI.Animation.enterContent(content2, { top: "0px", left: "350px" });
        })
}

content2.onclick = function () {
    WinJS.UI.Animation.exitContent(content2, { top: "0px", left: "350px" }).then(
        function () {
            return WinJS.Promise.timeout(200);
        })
        .done(function () {
            WinJS.UI.Animation.enterContent(content1, { top: "0px", left: "350px" });
        });
};
```

Comment: Cool, if it answers your question please mark it as the answer.

Comment: @sebagomez just out of interest, you use opacity to set the initial visible state. This presents a problem to me because content 2 sits on top of content 1 and prevents me from clicking anything in content 1. How would you hide it initially? I've tried setting it to display none but it doesn't show at all then?

Comment: I wouldn't know, but in that case I guess I would just use the same control with different content and manage a state myself, calling whatever is needed in each case